# Math Equation: What's wrong with my code? (Beginner Question)

Tags: overleaf

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{equation}
    w_{n} = \frac{1}{N_{d}} \sqrt{\frac{2\epsilon_{s}V_{bi}}{q(\frac{1}{N_{a}} + \frac{1}{N_{d}})}
    \end{equation}
    
    \end{document}
```

Can anyone help me spot where I'm getting an error here? Been going through this for ages trying to understand why it won't compile properly in Overleaf. It just returns a blank space in my document.

Comment: Maybe a closing bracket too many at the end? Just by looking at it, I did not test it.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I have tried changing that and checking that several times! Possibly though, however I've tried changing this a few times now with no resolution...

Comment: I think you are lacking a `}` at the end. `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 w_{n} = \frac{1}{N_{d}}
 \sqrt{\frac{2\epsilon_{s}V_{bi}}{q(\frac{1}{N_{a}} + \frac{1}{N_{d}})}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}` works.

Comment: it runs without error if you add the missing `}`

Comment: Please add a minimal working example so people can help faster. You are missing `}` at the end. Also, use modern IDE to help you avoid these mistakes by using automatic completion tools.

Comment: @CroCo Excuse my basic understanding, but what is Modern IDE? I'm using Overleaf for a University project and don't really have much prior knowledge of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        w_{n} = \frac{1}{N_d}\sqrt{\frac{2\epsilon_{s}V_{bi}}{q\left( \frac{1}{N_a} + \frac{1}{N_d}\right)}}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate your help!

Comment: Are you really sure you need all these packages for adding `}`?!

Comment: Sure NO. The preamble is added automatically and I dont edit it. Thanks.

Comment: I took the liberty of minimizing the code.