# How do I slant the Computer Modern root symbol?

Tags: symbols, math-operators, sqrt

Considering this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/624070/math-equation-whats-wrong-with-my-code-beginner-question), actually I not remember as I must straighten square root symbol to have the classic sqrt symbol. I have used (for example),

```
\def\mySqrt{\radical"0270373\relax}
```

but it not works. I not remember if I must to use `\mathstrut`, `\smash` or other....

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\def\mySqrt{\radical"0270373\relax}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        w_{n} = \frac{1}{N_d}\mySqrt{\frac{2\epsilon_{s}V_{bi}}{q\left( \dfrac{1}{N_a} + \dfrac{1}{N_d}\right)}}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit: 2021/11/27*

> **Why CM font give us a ugly, sometimes, root (not slanted) instead of other fonts? What is the reason?**

Comment: what do you mean by it doesn't work? It makes the output that you show, what do you want to change?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I mean that the square root should be lying more to the right with the classic pattern of a root.

Comment: the font only has sloping signs for a small range once you get to a large expression it has to be vertical as it is stretches to the size of the content by stacking vertical bits (the same as  `\left( ..\right)` goes straight at a certain size

Comment: @DavidCarlisle And if I use \vphantom{....} the size of the root become correctly?

Comment: You can preserve the sloping radical by replacing the `\dfrac` terms with inline-fraction equivalents, e.g., by replacing `\left( \dfrac{1}{N_a} + \dfrac{1}{N_d}\right)` with `(1/N_a + 1/N_d)`. :-)

Comment: @Mico Welcome in my question :-)))))))))))...yes I have understood (I think).

Comment: @Sebastiano - I just couldn't resist making this little comment... I know full well that the question is *not* about how one might modify the contents of the argument of `\sqrt` or `\mySqrt` in order to reduce the overall height.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\sum caused \sqrt to not be slanted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291216/sum-caused-sqrt-to-not-be-slanted)

Comment: ... that's what you want, right? Judging from the answer. Reading the question makes me think that  you want to "straighten" the square root instead, but both the "sloped" and the "vertical" one are "straight".

Comment: @user202729 I made an edit to my question hoping to be clearer. Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: The reason for the vertical stroke beyond a certain height is, as so many things in TeX and CM, the limited memory available when TeX was created.  A vertical stroke can be extended easily by adding small vertical segments, which will line up automatically; controlling the extension of a sloped line is much more complicated.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Grazieeeeeeeeeee. Please can you convert your comment in an answer with the history of this root?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your document allows using the `mtpro2` math font package, you could make use of that package's `\SQRT` macro to get square-root symbols with sloping surds [am I using the term "surd" correctly?], as long as the total height of the argument of `\SQRT` does not exceed 4", or 10 cm. The formulas in your publications will never contain such a monstrosity, though, right?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
\[
\sqrt{\frac{2\epsilon_{s}V_{bi}}{q\left( \dfrac{1}{N_a} + \dfrac{1}{N_d}\right)}}
\quad\mbox{vs.}\quad
\SQRT{\frac{2\epsilon_{s}V_{bi}}{q\left( \dfrac{1}{N_a} + \dfrac{1}{N_d}\right)}}
\qquad
\SQRT{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{8}{8}}{\dfrac{8}{8}}}{\dfrac{\dfrac{8}{8}}{\dfrac{8}{8}}}}{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{8}{8}}{\dfrac{8}{8}}}{\dfrac{\dfrac{8}{8}}{\dfrac{8}{8}}}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With `unicode-math` (in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX), you can replace the radical symbol with any other OpenType math font’s.  One of the few with a slanted radical is Garamond Math:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern}

\setmathfont{Garamond Math}[range=\surd,
                            Scale=MatchUppercase]

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        w_{n} = \frac{1}{N_d}\sqrt{\frac{2\epsilon_{s}V_{bi}}{q\left( \dfrac{1}{N_a} + \dfrac{1}{N_d}\right)}}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image: New Computer Modern + Garamond Math sample]

To better match the weight, I use New Computer Math Book.

Comment: Great ...Now I have understood the reason....."grazieeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee".

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't supply a large radical symbol with a slanted stroke as
requested in the question, but at the request of the OP, addresses the
history of the shape in the Computer Modern fonts.

As with so many things in TeX and CM, the reason for the vertical stroke
when the height exceeds a certain amount is the limited memory available
when TeX was created, along with the limited capabilities of available
imaging devices.

A vertical stroke can be extended easily by adding small vertical segments,
which will line up automatically.  Controlling the extension of a sloped
line is much more complicated.  It involves not only supplying a segment in
the font, but also the mechanism for joining successive segments precisely.
In fact, it is likely that more than one such segment, at different angles, would have to be provided, in the absence of the ability to redraw the
symbol at the time of imaging.  Only "static"  shapes were possible when
TeX was created.

Comment: Thank  you very muchhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh +1.